# Page previews in Jquery mobile or bootstrap sidebar menu like pdf pages

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, jquery-mobile

Hi I am developing cordova app, I have requirement to design some sidebar menu in both side of page. In side menu bar I have to display some images like pages 1, 2 and so on. Is it possible to desing like this? and please help me
Please check the attached image to clear idea.. Red circle is for images previews in both side and green button is for side menu bar toggle.[image]

Comment: Okay, but what is your actual question?

Comment: @Roberrrt  Sir, I want to design like this bootstrap or jquery mobile. Is it possible ?

Comment: That's way too broad to ask on SO. Try finding some tutorials or examples of what you want, start with it, and come back with us if your code isn't producing the desired results so we can assist you.

Comment: @Roberrrt Ok.. I am trying some examples now and post it again, if I get any doubts. Thank u